# Get value from component B in component A in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component for dropdown (name : JDrop) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,Picker,Image } from 'react-native';

export default class JDrop extends Component {
  constructor(props,state) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedValue:'',
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {items,sizeW,bColor} = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',height: 35, width: sizeW, alignItems: 'center',backgroundColor:bColor}}>
        <View>
          <Image style={{width:20,height:10, margin:5}} source={require('../../assets/Images/arrowb.png')}/>
        </View>
        <View >
          <Picker 
              mode='dropdown'
              style={{height: 35, width: sizeW,backgroundColor:bColor}}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})}
              prompt='Select...'
              >
                {
                   items.map( (item,ind) => (
                    <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.value} key={ind} />
                  ))
              }

              </Picker>
        </View>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I use it in App.js like :

```
<JDrop items={this.state.priority} sizeW={200} bColor={'blue'} ></JDrop>
```

how can I get **selectedValue** from **JDrop** in **App.js** ?

Comment: you have just one component posted `JDrop`. So what do you mean by `component B` and `component A`?

Comment: means access sth from JDrop in App.js

Comment: The react way I think would be to create a method in App.js and pass it to a property that you call in your JDrop component when it changes:

`<JDrop items={this.state.priority} onChange={this.itemChanged.bind(this)}>` (or similar).  Maybe you could also pass an object to a property and change a value on that object, but that isn't really the react way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways, but the easiest is to pass a change handler from the parent to the child that can communicate the changes in the child. Like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

   onChangeJDrop = (val) => {
       console.log(val)   
   }

   render() {
       return (
          <JDrop onChange={this.onChangeJDrop} items={this.state.priority} sizeW={200} bColor={'blue'} ></JDrop>
      )
   }
}


class JDrop extends React.Component {

   onValueChange = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
       this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})
       this.props.onChange(itemValue)
   }

   render() {
         return (
            <Picker onValueChange={this.onValueChange} />
         )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass in a callback into your JDrop component (named onSelect below):

```
<JDrop onSelect={this.onSelect} items={this.state.priority} sizeW={200} bColor={'blue'} ></JDrop>
```

Then in your JDrop component:

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
  this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})
  this.props.onSelect(itemValue)
} }
```